# How to get indices of outliers in a dataframe boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I have a dataframe and I want to get each columns of outliers indices.

Here is part of my dataframe;

`mediamarkt[,48]`

```
[1]  7126  4012  3711  3237  3432  2671  2861  7065  3158  4023  4770  3861
[13]  4108  7408  9071  3596  3889  4093  4446  6059  8345 10291  5546  5129
[25]  4683  4670  5694  8619 11047  5743  5775  5216  5283  4854  7871  9944
[37]  3797  3821  3834  3999  4577  8898 11396  4508  5459  3668  3885  4021
[49]  7491  8831  3513  3606  3332  3189  3656  6859  9167  3306  3305  3379
[61]  3507  3912  6562  8245  3420  3445  3530  3404  3847  7187  9128  3623
[73]  3581  3401  2784  3024  6342  7835  2766  2718  2578  2591  2737  5479
[85]  7064  2528  2550  2287  1893  1846
```

First of all I have tried to get value of outliers with this codes:

`boxplot(mediamarkt[,48])$out`  and  I get 2 outliers;

`[1] 11047 11396`

Everything is okey so far but when I need to get indices of outliers with these code below:

`which(mediamarkt[,48] %in% boxplot_mediamarkt$out)`

`[1]  5 18 29 43 59`

I get more than 2 outliers, it does not match these results

What is wrong with my codes

Could anyone help me about solve my problem?

Comment: Have you checked that all values are unique in the dataframe column? If not, then it is likely there are 5 indices which deliver 2 outliers.

Comment: You are testing against `boxplot_mediamarkt$out`   Not `boxplot(mediamarkt[,48])$out`   Are they really the same?

Comment: boxplot.stats gives outliers (or check which values are +/- 2xSD).

Comment: Thanks @G5W. Your comment was very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@G5W has asked a question that remains open. This code shows how to do easy input for your data and suggests that your `boxplot_mediamarkt` is not the output of `boxplot` or `boxplot.stats` from your data.

```
 dat <- scan()
1:   7126  4012  3711  3237  3432  2671  2861  7065  3158  4023  4770  3861
13:  4108  7408  9071  3596  3889  4093  4446  6059  8345 10291  5546  5129
25:  4683  4670  5694  8619 11047  5743  5775  5216  5283  4854  7871  9944
37:  3797  3821  3834  3999  4577  8898 11396  4508  5459  3668  3885  4021
49:  7491  8831  3513  3606  3332  3189  3656  6859  9167  3306  3305  3379
61:  3507  3912  6562  8245  3420  3445  3530  3404  3847  7187  9128  3623
73:  3581  3401  2784  3024  6342  7835  2766  2718  2578  2591  2737  5479
85:  7064  2528  2550  2287  1893  1846
91: 
Read 90 items
> boxplot(dat)$out
[1] 11047 11396
> which(dat %in% boxplot(dat)$out)
[1] 29 43
```